# Append Variable To Every Line Of Another Variable

Tags: linux, awk, sed, echo, paste

I would like to take the following data which is stored in `$variable1`:

```
term 1
term 2
term 3
```

And append `$variable2` which contains:

```
addition
```

So, it becomes:

```
term 1,addition
term 2,addition
term 3,addition
```

The trick is that it has be done using both as variables. I was thinking echo, paste, awk or sed. It could be something like this:

```
while read line $variable1; do echo "$line,$variable2"; done
```

I have played around with them but when variables and quoting get involved, I mess it up. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU bash and a [here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings):

```
while IFS='' read -r line; do echo "$line,$variable2"; done <<< "$variable1"
```

Output:

```
term 1,addition
term 2,addition
term 3,addition
```